# Why can I not see winlogon.exe using Python on top of Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, winlogon

This is the file I'm searching for on a Windows XP computer

```
C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
```

I have displayed file extensions for all files, checked Show Hidden Files, checked Show Hidden System Files, and I can see the file using Explorer but cannot see the file with python. I cannot even see the file using:

```
os.system( 'dir C:/Windows/System32/winlogon.exe' )
```

I can see the file by using command prompt by running

```
dir C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
```

[Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists): "On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists."

I'd like to use the regular python libraries to be able to do this. I also tried open() command. How do I go about finding this file using Python?

Note: I'm running Python27 under Cygwin in Windows XP. This is because I'm in networking and it's easier to write scripts that run off of Linux, ssh into Windows' Cygwin sshd client, in order to run things.

Comment: Surely, you've already found it? And hardly surprised the OS doesn't allow you access to it

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish here? surely more than simply seeing if the file exists

Comment: @JoranBeasley short of the case of checking existence (always the case here), I can't see any purpose that isn't possibly malicious

Comment: I just need to be able to detect if the file exists. If it does, my script will say it exists. I work for network security so we try to be the opposite of malicious by MD5ing important files.

Comment: Why that specific file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: win32api will probably help do what you are trying to do (assuming its not malicious) ... but basically if its windows it has that file ... but you will have a very hard time accessing it from python

Comment: I work for a company that MD5s important system files. If we cannot detect a certain file, then we cannot MD5 it. That's the reason.

Comment: I think the reason I may not be able to see that file is because it may be a 64 bit file. I'm running 64 bit XP in a VM but installed a 32 bit version of Cygwin by accident. I'm installing a new 64 bit cygwin with an sshd daemon, to test to see if its an architecture issue.

Comment: Source: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg00444.html

Comment: WOW. It was the issue. Apparently a 32 bit cygwin can only see 32 bit files but a 64 bit cygwin can see all files. I guess this wasn't a python issue at all. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: nice find :) ... weird i wonder if 32 bit python suffers the same issues ... because im not running through cygwin (although i am running 32bit python) and I cant see that file from python you should post it as an answer and accept it in a few days when you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using 64 bit Windows with 32 bit Cygwin. Apparently 32 bit Cygwin can only see 32 bit files while 64 bit Cygwin can see all the files.

Source: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg00444.html

This may be true for all 32 bit applications running on a 64 bit environment. Another reason for many 32 bit applications to upgrade to 64 bit if the applications plan to be run on present 64 bit machines.